# Is there a good framework or approach for restructuring JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, orm, mapping

I am writing an application in Node.js. I need to convert JavaScript objects returned from my database layer to JavaScript objects that I need to return from my REST service. I may need to add or remove certain properties or perhaps flatten out some structures. For example, here's a User object returned from the database layer:

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "username": "jsmith",
    "person": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith"
    }
}
```

The object that I want to return from the REST layer is

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": { "href": "/users/jsmith" },
    },
    "username": "jsmith",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

Here are the changes:

1. "id" property is removed
2. "links" section has been added
3. "person" object has been flattened out to the parent object
4. "first_name" and "last_name" properties have beed converted from snake_case to camelCase

I could obviously hand-code each one of these transformations, but that would be very inefficient and error prone. Do you know of any framework or approach that would ease this pain?

P.S. I am essentially looking for something similar to the Java framework called [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: i doubt there's much out there. what you describe is a million and one tiny little easy-to-code custom adjustments, not a large highly-repetitive common procedure that a framework can eliminate. the native way of re-composting object is so simple that it can't be made much easier, unless you have broad trends/patterns that you can build factories for.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. If you look at dozer, they do have a declarative way of doing this in Java. See here: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/deepmapping.html. In my example, it let's you say something like <a>person.first_name</a> <b>firstName</b> - no code required.

Comment: you might look into templater like mustach, or query tools like taffyDB, but a simple literal harness, given object `o` does what you need declarative: `{_links:{self:{href:"/users/"+o.userName}},username:o.username,firstName:o.first_name,lastName:o.last_name}`

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. The template idea seems very interesting. I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom function to convert the object returned from the DB before pushing them to the RESTAPI.

An example:

```
var dbObject = db.query(...); //this is what you get from your DB query

//Here is your REST API object that you will send back
var restObject = (function(obj){
  var link = {
    self: {
        href: "/users/" + obj.username
    }
  };

  var username = obj.username;
  var firstname = obj.person.first_name;
  var lastname = obj.person.last_name;

  return JSON.stringify({
    _links: link,
    username: username,
    firstName: firstname,
    lastName: lastname
  })

})(dbObject);
```

Obviously, this can be cleaned up/customized to fit your code (e.g: your DB query might be asynchronous, so the `restObject` will need to reflect that). Also, asssuming your DB sends back a JSON object, you will need to account for that.

Comment: Thanks @Bwaxxlo. This is what I meant by the "hand-coded" approach that I would take if no framework like dozer was available in JavaScript.